# Логика php

Tags: php

Доброе время суток. 
Есть скрипт - перебирает строки в директории:   Кому не в лом, большая просьба, объясните отдельные  моменты. Я новичок. Премного буду благодарен.

```
<?php 
$cur_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/iptest/city/";  //тут понятно
$cur_path = ""; //тут понятно
if ($handledir = opendir($cur_dir)) / //тут понятно - если директория открылась
{ 
echo "Directory handle: $cur_dir<br>";    //тут понятно
echo "Files:<br>";                        //тут понятно

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handledir)))   /вообще непонятно.
{ 
if( !(($file == ".") || ($file == "..")) )  /вообще непонятно.
{ 
$cur_path = $cur_dir;  /вообще непонятно.
// $cur_path .= "\"; 
$cur_path .= $file;      /вообще непонятно.
echo "$cur_path<br>";    /вообще непонятно.

// $handle = fopen("$cur_path", "r"); /тут понятно
// while (!feof($handle)) /тут понятно
// { 
// читаем содержимое файла /тут понятно
// } 
} 
} 
closedir($handledir); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: щас кто-нить запостит в ответ скрины лекций введения в аяп. :)

Answer (score 3):

Надо не мучиться, а использовать

```
$files = glob($cur_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'*.*')
```

для получения списка файлов в виде массива

Answer (score 2):

в в большинстве случаев, где вам непонятно выясняется и собирается путь к файлу, который потом распечатывается в строке с "`echo`",

проверка на сравнение имени файла с точкой или двумя точками `(if( !(($file == ".") || ($file == "..")) ))` - это проверка если элемент итерации по элементам папки не является переходом в родительскую или текущую директорию.

вообще, большой совет не пользоваться подобными велосипедами середины девяностых годов а посмотреть на [SPL класс DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), который специально для этого был сделан и включен в PHP начиная с php 5. По ссылке можно увидеть нормальные примеры. Получаемый код становится короче, чище и надежней

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$cur_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/iptest/city/";  //тут понятно
$cur_path = ""; //тут понятно
if ($handledir = opendir($cur_dir)) / //тут понятно - если директория открылась
{ 
echo "Directory handle: $cur_dir<br>";    //тут понятно
echo "Files:<br>";                        //тут понятно

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handledir)))   /читает имена файлов и папок в массив $file.
{ 
if( !(($file == ".") || ($file == "..")) )  /Потому что в *nix подобных ОС есть такие вот системные папки как . и .. мы их фильтруем потому как зачем они нам?
{ 
$cur_path = $cur_dir;  / Что тут понимать? Программист сморозил себе глубокий философский образ. Не нашего ума дело
// $cur_path .= "\"; 
$cur_path .= $file;      /Сложение строк. Путь к каталогу плюс имя файла
echo "$cur_path<br>";    /Выводит результат пользователю с переносом строки в браузере

// $handle = fopen("$cur_path", "r"); /тут понятно
// while (!feof($handle)) /тут понятно
// { 
// читаем содержимое файла /тут понятно
// } 
} 
} 
closedir($handledir); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: >Потому что в *nix подобных ОС есть такие вот системные папки как . и ..


Шикарно...

Comment: Знак текущей директории и знак родительской папки. И что не понятно?

Comment: А какое отношение это имеет к "системным папкам" и к unix?

Comment: klopp, нет ну сформулировал конечно через ж. А про точки то вроде ж под виндой не выдает их при использовании scandir.

Comment: Выдаёт :) Собственно, это стандарт для любого POSIX-совместимого opendir/readdir и их производных, в любой ОС где это в принципе возможно, даже в самых древних версиях DOS. И принимать в аргументах точки все умеют, можно посмотреть на вывод команды "dir ." или "dir ..", или даже dir "..\..\path" :-) (блин, слэши съедаются редактором)